# Indirect Recursive Ng-Template in Angular 6

Tags: angular6

```
<ng-template #list let-Items>
    <ul>
       <li *ngFor="let i of Items">
           <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="container" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: i}"></ng-container>
       </li> 
    </ul>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #container let-list>
// some code
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="list" [ngTemplateOutletContext]=" 
   {$implicit: list.columns}"></ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

I have a template "container" that includes another template "item".. the container "item" includes "container" again

This is not working, I'm getting this error:

**ERROR TypeError: templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function**

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This issue is quite old so you may already have found the answer but in case someone else encounter this.

The problem you had is a collision in the naming of the variable list (let-list) in your container template that overrides the list template.

If you rename the template to listTpl for example (or the variable) it should work correctly:

```html
<ng-template #listTpl let-Items>
    <ul>
       <li *ngFor="let i of Items">
           <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="container" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: i}"></ng-container>
       </li> 
    </ul>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #container let-list>
// some code
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="listTpl" [ngTemplateOutletContext]=" 
   {$implicit: list.columns}"></ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

For recursion inside template, we need to understand how ng-template works along with templateOutlet in angular. If we master it the we could make the recursion easily For the reference follow following code.

```
<ul>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveListTmpl; context:{ $implicit: serviceNavLinks }"></ng-container>
</ul>

<ng-template #recursiveListTmpl let-list>
<li *ngFor="let item of list">
    <a class="list-group-item no-border">
        {{item.linkTranslationKey | translate }}
    </a>
    <ul *ngIf="item.childNavLinks && item.childNavLinks.length > 0">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveListTmpl; context:{ $implicit: item.childNavLinks }"></ng-container>
    </ul>
</li>
```

This is tested in Angular 8. Did not checked for earlier versions of angular.